# Is there a way to know how many times my windows phone 8 app is open?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to make a message box that shows a message when my app is opened every 5 times, but i cant find a way to do it, is there a way to do it in C#?

Answer (score 2):

Either create a file in LocalStorage or a setting with the count in it.

Every time you open your app, you can increment the count, re-save the file, and then check `count % 5 == 0` to see if you should show your message or not.

Answer (score 1):

Based on WinForms application it's gonna be looking like this

int Count = 0;
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
        using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(new FileStream("file.bin", FileMode.OpenOrCreate)))
        {
            while (reader.BaseStream.Position < reader.BaseStream.Length)
            {
                Count = reader.ReadInt32();  Count++; 
            }
        }
        if (Count % 5 == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Count.ToString());
        }
    }
    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(new FileStream("file.bin", FileMode.Open)))
        {
            writer.Write(Count); 
        }
    }
```